# Find the smallest value of positive integer !!

Tags: arithmetic, integers

Find the smallest positive integer with exactly 30 positive factor

First, I use function $\tau$ to find the exponential that gives $2×3×5$ and I want to find the smallest value.
How can I find it use inequality to help

And how to find the value of $\sqrt{8×13×15×17+49}$? I get $x=8$ and doing perfect square ... but stuck who can help me, please

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you give some examples of the smallest value of a positive number with 2,3,4 positive factors? What do you mean with positive factors?

Comment: What have you tried?  Given the primne factorization $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ , do you know how to compute the number of factors of $n$?

Comment: @kvantour To me these feel like two separate questions that should have been asked separately, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The number of factors of a natural is given by the product of the multiplicities of its prime factors plus one, $(m_2+1)(m_3+1)(m_5+1)\cdots$.

To obtain $30=2\cdot3\cdot5$ factors, you need multiplicities $1,2$ and $4$, which you will assign to the smallest possible primes, by decreasing order

$$5^13^22^4=720.$$

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "exactly 5 positive factors"?  Are these **distinct** or can they be the same?  If the same then the smallest such integer is $2^5= 32$.  It they must all be different then it is 2(3)(4)(5)(6)= 720.

Comment: The question about distinctness doesn't make sense. $1$ has thirty factors $1$, and many more.

Comment: **Because** of that "1" is not usually considered a factor.

Comment: Don't you understand ?  $2$ has thirty factors $2$, and many more.